# Создание диалогов (сообщений) в приложении

Tags: java, android, kotlin

Пишу приложение, и необходимо реализовать диалоги сообщений, по типу как в Vk, Telegram и т.д.

Как это можно сделать? Какие библиотеки использовать или как правильнее будет написать?

Comment: Я примерно понимаю, о чем говорит автор: диалоговые окна в вк исчезают и изменяют размер по свайпу. Это действительно интересно

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1130603/265051

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Понятие -  `по типу как в Vk, Telegram и т.д.` максимально размытое и непонятное. Для создания диалогов вы можете использовать как сторонние библиотеки так и самостоятельно их создавать с нуля. Если вы склоняетесь в сторону библиотек, то [вот есть список](https://android-arsenal.com/tag/30) разнообразных диалогов и вы выбрав нужный достигнете своей цели. Если вы хотите самостоятельно создать и настроить диалог то для начала нужно создавать разметку для диалогового окна, например такая:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:background="@drawable/dialog_background"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
        android:text="@string/questionnaire_alert_message"
        android:textColor="@color/gray"
        android:textSize="16sp" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:background="@color/test_color" />


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="10">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/agree"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_weight="4.98"
            android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
            android:text="@android:string/yes"
            android:textColor="#CD0000"
            android:textSize="16sp" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.04"
            android:background="@color/test_color" />


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/cancel"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_weight="4.98"
            android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
            android:text="@android:string/cancel"
            android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
            android:textSize="16sp" />
    </LinearLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

дальше вы ее будете использовать при создании диалога:

```
private fun exitDialog() {
        val dialog = Dialog(context!!)
        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.polls_exit_dialogue)

        val window = dialog.window
        val wlp = window!!.attributes
        wlp.gravity = Gravity.BOTTOM
        window.attributes = wlp


        dialog.findViewById<View>(R.id.agree).setOnClickListener {
            dialog.dismiss()
            moveHome()
        }

        dialog.findViewById<View>(R.id.cancel).setOnClickListener {
            dialog.dismiss()
        }

        Objects.requireNonNull<Window>(dialog.window).setBackgroundDrawable(ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT))
        dialog.show()
    }
```

таким образом создавая такой диалог вы можете контролировать все этапы его создания и менять то что вам нужно и как нужно. Вот диалог из примера:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

### UPDATE

Как мне указал [@ЮрийСПб](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/17609/%D0%AE%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B9%D0%A1%D0%9F%D0%B1) есть вероятность что вы имели диалоги как общение между пользователями. То есть вопрос можно перефразировать так - "как сделать чат?". Опять таки это чисто гипотетическое предположение того что вы имели в виду. Для того чтобы реализовать такое в приложении нужно делать две части: клиентскую и серверную. За серверную я вам рассказать много не смогу, чтобы вас не запутать. А про клиентскую часть было рассказано в этом [вопросе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1150509/%D0%9C%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%B8-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%B6%D0%B5%D1%80/1150704#1150704).

Comment: Возможно ТС имел в виду диалог как список сообщений между пользователями)

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, возможно да, возможно нет)) так сложно что-то сказать не имея фидбека от ТС) я то ответ дополнил, но не факт что вы "угадали" :D

Comment: @Andrew да, Юрий прав) Я имел ввиду сделать чат

Comment: @Sergey1996, тогда я по ссылке писал как мессенджер сделать :) там при помощи библиотеки можно все сделать красиво, при условии что у вас есть чатовский сервер

Comment: @Andrew спасибо большое)